# Kendo UI & Javascript - Data not fetch when Add New Record

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Greeting all,

Need help and not sure which parts Im doing wrong.

When click **Add new record** I want **segmentActive** field to **disable** and by default radio button will checked on **YES**. 
I manage to do that. But when I save the record, it not fetch the value '**y**' into my database. It will insert null.

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
dataSource: dataSource,
height:400,
sortable: true,  
columns: [ 
    { field: "segmentActive", title:"STATUS", width: "120px" , editor: RadioSegmentActive,
      template: data => data.segmentActive == "y" ? "Yes" : "No" },

    { field: "marketSegmentName", title:"SEGMENT NAME", width: "120px" },

    //Button Name
    { command: [{ name: "edit", text: { edit: "Edit",
                                        update: "Submit", 
                                        cancel: "Cancel"} },
                { name: "destroy", text: "De-active" }], 
                  title: "&nbsp;", width: "120px" },

],
editable: "inline",
edit: function(e) {
        if (e.model.isNew()) { // Went adding new record    
                $('input[name=segmentActive]').attr("disabled",true);  //disable column STATUS
                radio3.checked = true; // id="radio3" checked
        }
    },   
toolbar: [{ name: "create", text: "Add" }],
pageable: {
            refresh: true,
            pageSizes: true,
            buttonCount: 5
        },          
});  //end of kendo grid
```

My RadioSegmentActive function

```
function RadioSegmentActive(container, options) {
var guid = kendo.guid();

    $('<input class="k-radio" id="radio3" name="segmentActive" type="radio" value="y" >').appendTo(container);
    $('<label class="k-radio-label" for="radio3">Yes</label>').appendTo(container);  //YES
    $('<br>').appendTo(container); 
    $('<input class="k-radio" id="radio4" name="segmentActive" type="radio" value="n" >').appendTo(container);
    $('<label class="k-radio-label" for="radio4">No</label>').appendTo(container);  //NO
}
```

Thank You in advance.

Comment: try to log the value of radio3. I guess you can´t disable it and then give the value. A solution should be having a hidden field to get the value after disable the radio button.

Comment: How to do that? if you dont mind please show me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is Kendo - you need to update the underlying model it binds to:

```
edit: function(e) {
    if (e.model.isNew()) { // Went adding new record    
            $('input[name=segmentActive]').attr("disabled",true);  //disable column STATUS
            radio3.checked = true; // id="radio3" checked
            // change the kendo model value
            e.model.set("segmentActive", "y");
    }
},
```

Comment: This method is more easy and worked fine for me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To check the value `console.log($('input[id=your_radio_button_id]:checked').val());` then check at the inspect window to see if it has a value. I guess not because it´s null on the database record.
Your edit function could include the update value into the hidden input.

```
edit: function(e) {
    if (e.model.isNew()) { // Went adding new record    
            $('input[name=segmentActive]').attr("disabled",true);  //disable column STATUS
            radio3.checked = true; // id="radio3" checked
            $("#hidden_input").val("y");
    }
},
```

Place the hidden input next to the radios

```
<input type="hidden" id="hidden_input" name="hidden_input">
```

Also change your back code to bind the hidden field with the Y instead of the radios.

Comment: I try this method but it still not fetch the value into my database because in my insert.php it fetch the value in segmentActive name. Btw, thanks, it give me a hint on other things.